# Pandas DataFrame multiplication by array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

DataFrame

```
A B C
1 2 3
2 4 6
```

---

```
array = [1,10,100]
```

Result:

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
2   4   6
10  20  30
20  40  60
100 200 300
200 400 600
```

Array and dataframe length can be of any size, not necessarily the same.

I have done using FOR loop which is too slow if I have large dataframe or too many of them.

Below is my sample snippet:

```
for i in array:
    pr[pr.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns] *= i
    fdf = np.concat([fdf,pr],axis=0)
```

Is there a much faster way to do this. I am dealing with multiple dataframes which after this operation needs to concatenated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mult = df.values * np.array([1,10,100])[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
pd.DataFrame(mult.reshape((-1, 3)), columns=df.columns)

     A    B    C
0    1    2    3
1    2    4    6
2   10   20   30
3   20   40   60
4  100  200  300
5  200  400  600
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.concat`

```
pd.concat([df * n for n in a], ignore_index=True)

     A    B    C
0    1    2    3
1    2    4    6
2   10   20   30
3   20   40   60
4  100  200  300
5  200  400  600
```

---

### Setup

```
io_ = pd.io.common.StringIO

def rpd(text='', sep='\s{1,}', *args, **kwargs):
  kw = dict(engine='python', sep=sep)
  return pd.read_csv(io_(text), *args, **kw, **kwargs)

df = rpd("""\
A B C
1 2 3
2 4 6""")

a = np.array([1, 10, 100])
```

Comment: `ignore_index=True` ?

Comment: Yes (-: was getting there

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.values*x for x in ary]))
Out[171]: 
     0    1    2
0    1    2    3
1    2    4    6
2   10   20   30
3   20   40   60
4  100  200  300
5  200  400  600
```

pandas `reindex`

```
df.reindex(df.index.tolist()*(len(ary))).reset_index(drop=True).mul(pd.Series(np.repeat(ary,len(df))),0)
Out[201]: 
     A    B    C
0    1    2    3
1    2    4    6
2   10   20   30
3   20   40   60
4  100  200  300
5  200  400  600
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[2,4],'C':[3,6]})
ar = [1,10,100]

result = pd.concat([df * i for i in ar], ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: This is exactly my answer